Unable to register a Container Instance with ECS
I have a backend app that I have dockerized and want to run it on ECS using EC2 Launch Type , This backend app Is connected to RDS Instance In another account (i.e. backend app and RDS Instance are not In the same VPC) , So I have set up a VPC Peering Connection between them both.
After creating the Service , It Is Stuck in CREATE_IN_PROGRESS state , and I fixed It by following this answer as a guide https://repost.aws/questions/QUIz_pDFKUQ-222yiXF9wmww/ecs-service-creation-is-stuck-in-create-in-progress-status ,But after setting back the desired count to 1 , the task Is In a Provisioning State forever , I followed this troubleshooting guide https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/ecs-tasks-stuck-pending-state , and after ssh into the ec2-Instance which Is supposed to host task and viewing the ecs.agent.log I can see these repeating messages in a loop
Connected to TCS endpoint

Websocket connection established.

Connected to ACS endpoint

Successfully loaded ebs-csi-driver container image from tarball

"Successfully loaded Managed Daemon image

Image excluded from cleanup" image="ebs-csi-driver:latest"

TCS WebSocket connection closed for a valid reason

Reconnecting to ACS immediately without waiting

Using cached DiscoverPollEndpoint

Establishing a Websocket connection

Websocket connection established

Connected to ACS endpoin

this is my task definition
{
    "family": "abc",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "abc-container",
            "image": "<xyz>.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/my-backend:latest",
            "cpu": 1024,
            "memoryReservation": 1024,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "name": "abc",
                    "containerPort": 8080,
                    "hostPort": 8080,
                    "protocol": "tcp",
                    "appProtocol": "http"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "MYSQL_DATABASE",
                    "value": "value-1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "MYSQL_USERNAME",
                    "value": "value-2"
                },
                {
                    "name": "MYSQL_PASSWORD",
                    "value": "value-3"
                },
                {
                    "name": "MYSQL_PORT",
                    "value": "value-3"
                },
                {
                    "name": "MYSQL_HOST",
                    "value": "value-4"
                }
            ],
            "environmentFiles": [],
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "ulimits": [],
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/my-backend",
                    "awslogs-region": "us-east-2",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                },
                "secretOptions": []
            },
            "systemControls": []
        }
    ],
    "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::<xyz>:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::<xyz>:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "EC2"
    ],
    "cpu": "1024",
    "memory": "3072",
    "runtimePlatform": {
        "cpuArchitecture": "ARM64",
        "operatingSystemFamily": "LINUX"
    }
}

This is my Dockerfile
FROM maven:3.9.6-eclipse-temurin-8 AS build
# Set Working Directoryc
WORKDIR /app
# Copy the pom.xml and the project files to the container
COPY pom.xml .
COPY src ./src
# Build the application using maven
RUN mvn clean package -DskipTests

#Use an Official eclipse-temurin image as the base Image
FROM --platform=linux/arm64 eclipse-temurin:8-jre
#set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
#Copy the built JAR file from the previous stage to the container
COPY --from=build /app/target/my-app.jar .
#set the command to run the application
CMD ["java","-jar","my-app.jar"]

This is my Docker Compose File where I reference the env variables defined in the task
version: '3.7'
services:
   my-app:
    container_name: my-app
    build:
       context: .
       dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_HOST=${MYSQL_HOST}
      - MYSQL_USERNAME=${MYSQL_USERNAME}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      - MYSQL_PORT=${MYSQL_PORT}

Parameters I used to create the Cluster :

AWS EC2 Instances Selected
AWS Fargate Unselected
Created new ASG
AMI : Amazon linux 2 (kernel 5.10)
Desired Capacity: min 0 , max: 1
SSH pem key enabled
Instance type : t3.medium (2 vCPU, 4 GB Memory)

Network :

VPC ( chose the VPC Which is Peered with the VPC which has the RDS Instance )

Subnet ( Only chose the Private Subnet with a NAT Gateway and a route to the peered VPC)

Security Group ( allowing All TCP Inbound Connections on all Ports)


I have checked the ecs.agent.log to see If there any other errors, but nothing Is relevant , I have checked the the roles and Permissions associated with my task and I can see that It has ecsInstanceRole attached , I have followed the troubleshooting guide mentioned here
https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/ecs-tasks-stuck-pending-state
but with no luck
